# jbuilder access to nested models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jbuilder

class `Parent`

```
belongs_to :condition
has_many   :conditionregions, through: :condition
```

class `Condition`

```
translates :description, :fallbacks_for_empty_translations => true
globalize_accessors
```

class `Conditionregion`

```
belongs_to :region
```

With jbuilder the associations can be chained on parent defined relatives, including translations,

```
json.conditionregions @event.condition.conditionregions, :region_id
json.translations @event.condition.translations, :locale, :description
```

However, extracting the related data of a relation returns a `NoMethodError undefined method`region`

```
json.regions @event.condition.conditionregions.region, :name
```

How can this latter information be accessed?  Must the model also chain down (and how to do so?) or is there a syntaxic hoop to jump through?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
json.regions @event.condition.conditionregions.joins(:region).pluck('region.name')
```

Comment: unfortunately not.  `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "region"

Comment: What is the name of table mapped with region model?
regions? If so, try `...pluck('regions.name')`

Comment: no, it was `region`.  I am not sure jbuilder allows to chain past what si defined in model.rb file.  Comments allude to this fact, while the gem instructions provide a path to do so...

Answer (score 0):

RTFM, [as per gem instructions](https://github.com/rails/jbuilder)

```
json.regions @event.condition.conditionregions do |conditionregion|
  json.name conditionregion.region.name
end
```